# Shutting down mysqld in Cygwin

Tags: windows-8, cygwin, mysql

How are you supposed to shutdown mysqld faster from Cygwin (without killing the process in Task Manager) and prevent these errors?

This is how I started it:

```
$ /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &
[1] 4440

Chloe@xps ~
$ 130809 17:27:09 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/xps.err'.
chown: invalid user: `mysql'
130809 17:27:10 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

When I try to shut it down, it prints this forever and won't respond to ^C:

```
$ /usr/sbin/mysqld.exe shutdown
130809 17:29:26 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
130809 17:29:26 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130809 17:29:26 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130809 17:29:26 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130809 17:29:26 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
130809 17:29:26 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130809 17:29:26 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
130809 17:29:26  InnoDB: Retrying to lock the first data file
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

It finally pretends to shut down after 3 minutes of printing those errors repeatedly, but it really doesn't shut down because it is still in Task Manager and ps list. I don't think it should take that long.

```
130809 17:31:06 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I also tried

```
$ mysqladmin shutdown
```

but that appears to hang.

Comment: We meet again, my nemesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that probably the user already found how to shutdown MySQL, but I just had the same issue and this was the first hit on google.

The trick was to add the host **as the IP address** and user on the command (if I used localhost as the host, the command would hang up).

```
 mysqladmin.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -u root shutdown
```

@Chloe there are a few of scenarios where this might not work. The 2 most common I think are if MySQL is bound to a different IP or if it's bound to a different port (the other scenarios are if MySQL is not using TCP, but one of the other transport protocols).

So, for example, after I run `mysqld_safe &` and mysql starts, then when I run the command netstat I can see that it's listening and on the default port 3306

```
$ netstat -an | grep 3306
```

**I hope this helps!**

---

### edit

If MySQL is not running, you'll need to provide a connection timeout (`--connect-timeout=N`) as by default mysqladmin waits forever to connect to the server. For example, if MySQL is not running

```
$ mysqladmin.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -u root --connect-timeout=5 shutdown

mysqladmin: connect to server at '127.0.0.1' failed
error: 'Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (4)'
Check that mysqld is running on 127.0.0.1 and that the port is 3306.
You can check this by doing 'telnet 127.0.0.1 3306'
```

Here, the command waits for 5 seconds before giving up. From my point of view, it doesn't make sense that it waits forever, but that's the default that mysql picked up :S.

Comment: That appears to hang too.

Comment: It hangs if mysqld is not running, but works if it is running. Weird.

Comment: Ahh! By default mysqladmin waits forever to connect to the server :(. Please see my edit!